# When reviewing a Question that belongs to another site, why is there only 5 other sites listed

Tags: feature-request, review, migration, off-topic

When I review a Question with close votes, and it belongs to another site but is still a valid question, the only available sites are :

- [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
- [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

But sometimes other StackExchange sites may be relevant, including (but maybe not limited to) :

- [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [android.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Why can't I specify any of these sites when it's relevant ? For now I usually close as `Off-topic > Other` and specify the site in free text. It would be nice to be able to specify the StackExchange site through a dropdown list, or just pasting the url of the site.

Comment: *"This is a "Don't Make Me Think" barrier; we don't want to present closers with a list of 12 different destinations and make them suss out which one is correct. There should be 4 most frequently correct destinations + meta."* - Jeff Atwood

Comment: Basically the situation is like this because we, as a community, suck at migration.

Comment: @Bart this question comes up so much that I think that should be a close reason.